# Email a Javascript object with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have a JavaScript function that downloads a JPG of a finger swipe signature of a user. I would like to be able to take that object and mail it via PHP but am unsure how I could possibly do this without having to download the file first, then upload it. Below is my JavaScript function.

```
saveJPGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    download(dataURL, "signature.jpg");
  }
});
```

Comment: Submit the path (or file name) to the PHP service, then load the file using server-side PHP and attach to the email in PHP.

Comment: @daddygames - That might work. Since I know where the file is going to be downloaded to I could try that method out

Comment: Or you may simply upload the file to the server, decode from dataURL and attach to your email.

Comment: @ivogelov - That's actually what I did. I saved the dataURI into a field in the database and pull from that as needed.